# Non-serializable values were found in the navigation state React Navigation 5

Tags: firebase, react-native, react-navigation-v5

I am doing phone authentication in react native.

On screen no.1 I entered the phone number to get the response and then passing that response on screen no.2 which is OTP verification screen to verify the code this is how I have done.

```
const confirmation= auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(mobileno,true).then(confirmResult => {     
      if(confirmResult._auth._authResult){
      setConfirm(confirmResult);
      navigation.navigate('otp',{confirmation:confirmResult,mobileno:mobileno}) // this line shows warning
}
}-....
```

It shows warning **Non-serializable values were found in the navigation state**. so how can i pass that response to my next screen so that I can verify the OTP.
Thanks

Comment: You are recursively passing the value of `confirmation`, which is a `Promise`. Promises can't be serialized. I don't know the details here, but maybe try passing `confirmResult` instead of `confirmation`

Comment: Thanks – Łukasz Karczewski  that was typo, I had edited, but still get the same warning when passing the confirmResult

Comment: What kind of a warning does the last one show?

Comment: Non-serializable values were found in the navigation state. Check:

otp > params.confirmation._auth._app._deleteApp (Function)

This can break usage such as persisting and restoring state. This might happen if you passed non-serializable values such as function, class instances etc. in params.